# Question on Plyr error: Error in as.double(y) : cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'

Tags: r, plyr

I am upgrading a project I had working previously. This code worked a few months ago, in the meantime I have upgraded R and plyr. I think I was on R1.10 and now I am on R1.35, I am not sure what version of plyr I was running before but my current installed version is 1.2.

Here is what I am trying to run:

```
library(plyr)
library(twitteR)

tw <- head(ldply(searchTwitter("rstats", session=getCurlHandle(), n=10), function(x) data.frame(text=text(x), favorited=favorited(x), created=created(x), truncated=truncated(x), id=id(x), statusSource=statusSource(x), screenName=screenName(x))))
```

I always get the same error message now.

```
Error in as.double(y) : 
  cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Jason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In amongst your confusion about what versions you are running (there wasn't an R version 1.35!!), there are several issues. (To find out what versions of R and packages you are running, try `sessionInfo()`.)

First, the error you are getting comes from your use of `text()`. It should be `statusText()`.

Second, it seems like some of the functions/methods are not being exported in the package NAMESPACE. You can make it work by specifying the correct namespace when calling the function, as per the example below, but you should email the package maintainer (Jeff Gentry - contact details on [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twitteR/index.html)). You can refer to unexported functions using the `:::` operator. `:::` takes the package/namespace name on the left-hand side, with the function name on the right hand side, e.g.:

```
twitteR:::statusSource(x)
```

Here is a full working version of your example:

```
library(plyr)
library(twitteR)
## simplify the call to see what is going on - function first
fooFun <- function(x) {
    data.frame(text = statusText(x), favorited=favorited(x),
               created=created(x), truncated=twitteR:::truncated(x),
               id=id(x), statusSource=twitteR:::statusSource(x),
               screenName=screenName(x))
}
## now ldply it
out <- ldply(searchTwitter("rstats", session = getCurlHandle(), n = 10), fooFun)
## show some of it:
head(out)
```

Comment: ah, yes. It was R.app GUI v1.35 and R version 2.12.

Comment: Thanks for putting this example together, I learned a lot from it and it definitely solved my problem.

Comment: Hi there - I told Gavin this privately, but just so it is on a public forum, this was an oversight on my part.  I've updated the package to export those methods.  It might be a day or two before I can upload the package, but the new version will be 0.9.2.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

This works in the current version of R (2.12.0) and version 0.91 of twitteR:

```
tw <- ldply(searchTwitter("rstats", session=getCurlHandle(), n=10), 
              function(x)  c(text=x@text, favorited=x@favorited, created=x@created, 
                             truncated=x@truncated, id=x@id, statusSource=x@statusSource, 
                             screenName=x@screenName )
                          )
```

I was getting the same error as you were until I switched over to the "@" operator for accessing the slot values.

Comment: Whenever I see code delving inside of objects with `$` and `@`, I am compelled to issue a small warning ;-) It likely makes no difference, in this case, to use `@` and grab the bits you want. But as a general use-case I think it is *bad*. If there are extractor functions available, users should be encouraged to use them. There are cases where what is stored in an object under a particular name may not be what the user expects (working, not actual, residuals for example with some models). 99 times out of 100 you will be fine, but that 1 time you might get your ass well and truly bitten.

Comment: @ Gavin: No disagreement. It was only after trying the method the OP used, failing at getting text(x) to work and looking at the documentation for that particular S4 class that I switched over.